# how to update sub object in array (update) MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to update the only where "sku": "abcd"
the
"recived": 34,
to
"recived": 50,

I tried to solve it using updateOne(

)
But unfortunately I get errors

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62684e70e89eca781cc4f384"
  },
  "user": "ronen",
  "roles": {
    "User": 2001,
    "Editor": 1984,
    "Admin": 5150
  },
  
  "Stock": [
    {
      "sku": "777",
      "productname": "rone4n",
      "sendout": 5,
      "recived": 3,
      "totalinstock": 55,
      "location": "A770770",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "626a9bb384cd350c6e784794"
      }
    },
    {
      "sku": "abcd",
      "productname": "ron",
      "sendout": 43,
      "recived": 34,
      "totalinstock": 444,
      "location": "fff",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "626adab728fcc6005453a481"
      }
    }
  ],
 
}
```

I prefer to do this on the MongoDB side

I expect to get something like this

```
"sku": "abcd",
      "productname": "ron",
      "sendout": 43,
      "recived": 50,
      "totalinstock": 444,
      "location": "fff",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "626adab728fcc6005453a481"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at the end
After reading online
Thanks to whoever helped
I attach the code
Maybe it will help others

```
await User.updateOne(
    {
        Stock: {
            $elemMatch: {
                sku: req.body.sku
            }
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
            "Stock.$.recived": addrecived
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.update()` method with `$set` to update the value.

```
db.collection.update({
  "stock.sku": "abcd"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "stock.$.recived": 50
  }
})
```

You can check [mongo playground here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rlA9-t5oGAJ)

Comment: Thank you
But I can not use the updae function
Because it alerts me that it's Deprecated mongosh Method                                                    
You can see it here      
( https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)
And when I try with updateOne it does not work

Comment: What errors are you getting?